# Closing user account in DocuSign using api

Tags: c#, docusignapi

Is there any api to transfer active envelopes to other users in same organisation in the same account?

Or 
Another way get the list of envelopes of a specific user using api

Comment: same account? the envelopes are per account, not per user. Or you mean a different account inside the same organization?

Comment: if you are admin of the account, you should already have access

Comment: but anything else would require a support call.

Comment: Thanks Inbar, but I am looking for api reference for the transfer envelopes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only do this via the older SOAP API:

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-soap-api/reference/post-processing-group/transferenvelope. Here is how to do that in C#:

```
// Request the envelope specified to be transferred to the account specified
DocuSignWeb.TransferEnvelopeStatus status = _apiClient.TransferEnvelope("envelope ID", "account ID as GUID", "user ID as GUID");

// Confirm that the transfer succeeded
Console.WriteLine("Transfer succeeded? {0}", status.TransferEnvelopeSuccess);
```

I would recommend you consider the need to build this as an integration. If this is something that's more of a one-off, I would just call customer support to handle this.